# Liferay - Remotely created JournalArticle not available for display until Published

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have been working on the creation of a JournalArticle in a remote portal. I created the Article successfully. But when I try to search it through a Web Content Display, it is not available.

It becomes available only when I manually go and publish the article in the remote portal.

Is there a way to make the article available for display without manually publishing it?

Please follow the imaged below for clarifications.

New Title1 is the JournalArticle I created in the remote portlet. The below image shows the article right after creation.

[image]

I try to select this article to the web content display.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see above, I cannot find the article.
I go back and publish the article manually.

[image]

Then I can find the article in the web content search.

[image]

This is really painful, as we need to find the journal as soon as it is created in the portal. Do anyone know why this problem is arising? And what could be the solution for this?

**EDIT**: Added the code to create JournalArticle in remote portal.

```
journalArticleSoap = journalSoap.addArticle(
    remoteGroupId,
    journalFolderSoap.getFolderId(),
    article.getClassNameId(),
    article.getClassPK(),
    "",
    true,
    LocalizationUtil.getAvailableLanguageIds(article.getTitle()),
    titleMapValues.toArray(new String[titleMapValues.size()]),
    LocalizationUtil.getAvailableLanguageIds(article.getDescription()),
    descriptionMapValues.toArray(new String[descriptionMapValues.size()]),
    content,
    article.getType(),
    article.getStructureId(),
    remoteTemplateKey,
    article.getLayoutUuid(),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.HOUR),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, //expirationDate
    article.getExpirationDate() == null,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    true,
    article.isIndexable(),
    article.getUrlTitle(),
    serviceContext);
```

`journalSoap` is JournalArticleServiceSoap object of remote portal.
`remoteGroupId` is the Global group id of remote portal
`journalFolderSoap` is the JournalFolderSoap object of folder created in remote.
`article` is the JournalArticle in the local portal.
`remoteTemplateKey` is the templateKey of the remote template created.

Comment: How you create the articles?? Can you show us some code? It seems a workflow status problem, maybe until manual publish the article is in Pending status??

Comment: @MarcoMercuri Updated with the code to create article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't understand why the issue was arising. But I saw that the issue got fixed when I executed "Reindex all search indexes" under Admin Control Panel.

So I wrote a code to execute this automatically which is as follows.

```
try {
    String[] companyIdArray = new String[1];
    companyIdArray[0] = ""+PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId();
    Indexer indexer=IndexerRegistryUtil.getIndexer(JournalArticle.class);
    indexer.reindex(companyIdArray);
} catch (PortalException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I provided the above code in the remote portlet controller and made a REST call to it. Executing this in the remote environment after creating the JournalArticle fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
journalArticleSoap = journalSoap.addArticle(
    //your code
);

journalSoap.updateStatus(journalArticleSoap.getGroupId(),
    journalArticleSoap.getArticleId(), 1, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, 
    journalArticleSoap.getUrlTitle(), serviceContext);
```

Comment: it seems like it is working.. I will test some more and accept your answer. thanks :-)

Comment: hi.. I am sorry but it seems to be not working.. :-(